# Почему в reader записывается null?

Tags: c++, char, null

Есть такой вот код:

```
finA.open(filename);
char* str = new char[size];
finA.getline(str, size);
char* reader;
finA.close();
char* next_token1;
reader = strtok_s(str, ";,", &next_token1);
while (reader)
{
    char* next_token2;
    int datecount = 0;
    int currentposmain = 0;
    char * datemain;
    datemain = GetElement(reader, 3, &currentposmain, next_token1);
    finA.open(filename);
    char* str1 = new char[size];
    finA.getline(str1, size-1);
    char* reader1;
    finA.close();
    reader1 = strtok_s(str1, ";,",&next_token2);
    while (reader1) 
    {
        int currentpossub = 0;
        char* datesub;
        datesub = GetElement(reader1, 3, &currentpossub,next_token2);

        if (!_stricmp(datemain, datesub)) 
        {
            datecount++;
        }
        cout << reader1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5 - currentpossub + 1; i++)
        {
            reader1 = strtok_s(nullptr, ";,",&next_token2);
        }
        
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 - currentposmain  + 1; i++) 
    {
        reader = strtok_s(nullptr, ";,", &next_token1);
    }
    if (!mindatecount || datecount < mindatecount)
    {
        mindatecount = datecount;
        mindate = datemain;
    }
    delete[] str1;
}
char* GetElement(char* str, int elementpos, int *currentpos,char* token) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < elementpos-*currentpos; i++) 
    {
        str = strtok_s(nullptr, ";,", &token);
    }
    *currentpos += elementpos;
    return str;
}
```

И я столкнулся с проблемой, оба цикла while исполняются только 1  раз, из-за того что в reader почему-то записывается null.